# Setting width to remainder width of parent element

Tags: html, css

I want to have a side nav of `width: 150px;` and then the content floating next to it. I want the content to be 100% minus the 150px side nav width. Is this possible?

I know I can do it in Javascript, but I would much rather know a simple CSS solution, something that would be:

```
width:100%-150px;
```

Is there such a solution?

Answer (score 4):

> I want the content to be 100% width, minus the 150px side nav width.
>   Is this possible?

Yes:

```
width: calc(100% - 150px);
```

**N.B.** Be sure to **leave a space** either side of the minus sign. The CSS parser needs to be clear it is parsing a minus sign, followed by a positive integer.

Comment: This is an experimental technology.
Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Although, I do prefer this answer for it's simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to achieve that, here are a few of them.

### 1. using `float` + `overflow`:

Note, the content box shouldn't set any float on it, and `overflow:auto` can prevent [wrapped text](https://jsfiddle.net/vdxqk7yk/) going under the sidebar box.

```css
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.sidebar {
  background: pink;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.content {
  background: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

### 2: using `float` + `calc`:

See the [browser support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) - IE9+ basically.

```css
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.sidebar {
  background: pink;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.content {
  background: gold;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

### 3. using `display:inline-block` + `calc`:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0; /*remove white space*/
}
.sidebar, .content {
  font-size: 16px; /*reset font size*/
  display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar {
  background: pink;
  width: 150px;
}
.content {
  background: gold;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

### 4. using CSS table:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar, .content {
  display: table-cell;
}
.sidebar {
  background: pink;
  width: 150px;
}
.content {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

### 5. using flexbox:

See the [browser support tables](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) - IE10+ with [prefixes](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
  background: pink;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
.content {
  background: gold;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another ways is to make the side nav float and then have the main content be width 100% and include a padding of 150px on the same side as the nav

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to specify

```
.content {
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   right: 150px;
}
.sidenav {
   float: right;
   margin-right: -150px;
}
```

instead of `width: 100%` for the content. Note: I assumed relative positioning on the parent element (which would contain both the content and side nav).

Good luck!